# [error]Unexpected token : in JSON at position 3

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

We have an in house TFS server. We are trying to configure the build and getting an unexpected token error.

We have installed the sdk on the server. 
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/current

we are able to build the solution properly on Azure DevOps Service. 
[image]

Comment: Can you enable Diagnostic logs check box before running the build and check what’s happening before this error?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm getting the problem today after setting up my first build pipeline for a .Net6 solution.

Comment: @AndrewStephens: Try to use the latest Agent Specification.

Comment: Sorted it thanks, by changing that build task's version from `0.*` to `2.* preview`.